# Use pending intent created in Service class in MainActivity (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

So I'm trying to get a pending intent I created in my Service class into my Main Activity so I can use it when a button is clicked. If anyone is wondering why I need this Intent its because the NotificationListener grabs the notifications intent so when i click my button I can open that intent to get into the app the notification was originally from.

NotificationService Class

```
package com.apps.skytek.notify;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {





    private WindowManager windowManager;

    Context context;

    private AchievementUnlocked Notify;

    PendingIntent notifIntent;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private StatusBarNotification sbn;


    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService("notification");


    }
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();


        Log.i("Package", pack);
        Log.i("Ticker", ticker);
        Log.i("Title", title);
        Log.i("Text", text);


        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        String s = sbn.getPackageName();
        //cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());

        notifIntent = notification.contentIntent;
        try {
          notifIntent.send();
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
```

Comment: ok. good for you. but usually people ask questions.

Comment: @njzk2 I asked a valid question I don't know why this community always make me feel stupid, and puts me down for a legitimate question.

Comment: you didn't ask a question, that's the problem

Comment: @njzk2 HERE IS THE QUESTION: How can I use a pending intent that I made in my NotificationService Class in my MainActivity class?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, what you want is a way for your Service to communicate with an Activity.

There are many ways to do it, depending on the case.

[Using a LocalBroadcast](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/) would be a possible approach.

You can also check out [LocalService example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample).

Also check out [BoundServices](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Since you haven't provided more context it's hard to recommend a specific one, but the simplest of all is probably the `LocalBroadcast`.